# Executar o AngularJS em projeto SILEX

Tags: angularjs, silex

Pessoal tenho um backend todo feito em SIlex rodando perfeitamente, ai o meu cliente me enviou o frontend feito em Angular, como eu nunca usei o Angular gostaria de saber onde eu coloco os htmls, JS, CSS deste frontend. E como eu crio a rota padrão para chamar o index.html. Eu so preciso desta rota pois todas as outras são geradas pelo AngularJS.

Obrigado

A estrutura que ele me enviou foi a seguinte:

```
Public
|->css
|->img
|->js
|->sources
|->views
|->index.html
```

Se eu executar isto com php -S localhost:8080 -t public, funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: João, você deverá colocar esses recursos em sua camada de apresentação. Sobre as rotas, documentação do Angularjs https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: @AlexandreMaeda quando eu disse como ficaria a rota padrão é a rota que o Silex deverá criar para chamar o index.html e depois o Angular assume o serviço das rotas. Agora sobre os arquivos tenho que jogar todas as pastas citas dentro da minha pasta view onde estam os arquivos de visualização do TWIG?

Comment: Você utiliza twig para o projeto? Eu não sei como o pessoal costuma usar Views no Silex, porque eu usei o meu próprio sistema de Views.